# Need to SLOW DOWN EXECUTION BY atleast 5 SECONDS

Tags: java, arrays, performance, execution

I wrote a Java program which is used to calculate the largest cycle in different cycles of integers. My code is pretty quick and results within milliseconds on my quad core A8 AMD processor.

I want to slow down the execution by at least 5 seconds. Is there anything I could add into the code to slow it down?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SNASA {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long i,j,n,max=0, pos=0, x, y;
        long count=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the positive integer :");
        while(sc.hasNextLong()) {
            x=System.currentTimeMillis();
            i = sc.nextLong();
            long arr[] = new long [60000000];
            for(long p=i/2;p<i;p++) {
                arr[(int)p]=0;
            }
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                n=j;
                count=0;
                tag:while(n!=1) {
                    if(n<60000000) {
                        if(arr[(int)(n-1)]!=0) {
                            count = count + arr[(int)(n-1)];
                            break tag;
                        }
                    }
                    if(n%2==0) {
                        n = n/2;
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        n = (2*n)+n+1;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(j<60000000)
                    arr[(int)(j-1)]=count;
                if(count>max) { 
                    max=count; pos=j; 
                }
                count=0;
            }
            y=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Maximum Cycle length occurs at "+pos+" and the number of steps in cycle "+max+"\n Total time taken is "+(y-x)+"ms");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer obviously involves lowering your CPU's clock speed.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to see the results before the program closes.  There are better ways (prompt before closing)

Comment: @admdrew I'm probably gonna get flamed for saying this, but I don't think a CPU with a sufficiently low clock speed will be able to start the JVM in a reasonable amount of time. :)

Comment: @Mysticial So 4.2s for the startup..

Comment: Is there a way i could slow down without using Thread.Sleep();  ?

Comment: What specific functionality do you want that Thread.sleep() does not provide?

Comment: Explain why do you need to slow down your process. We don't have a magic crystal ball that explains your specific requirements about your work to completely understand the problem.

Comment: @Mystical can i make any changes to the code, without using Thread.sleep(); to delay the execution? ..if i use Thread.sleep(); my execution will be delayed as a whole, i.e whether i calculate for 100 or for 10000000 the execution will be delayed for 5 seconds, but i want my program to be executed slowly..but not 5 seconds in all cases.. i want it to be 1 second for 100 and 8-10 seconds for 10000000

Comment: Then you can put `Thread.sleep()` with a shorter time limit inside one of your loops. Depending on how many times the loop runs, your program will be delayed by a different amount overall.

Comment: Run the JVM inside http://bellard.org/jslinux/. Slowdown depends on which browser you use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pause execution for 5 seconds exactly as follows:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

This will stop the program exactly at that line, wait the duration specified, and then continue.

Also note that the [parameter is milliseconds, not seconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

Since the program will pause wherever this line is placed, if you want the amount of overall delay to depend on how many iterations you run, you can keep it inside of a loop and there will be a delay every time the loop runs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread.sleep(1000); //Delays 1s 10 times; 10s overall delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Thread.sleep(5000)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) to add a delay for 5 seconds.

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, *subject to the precision and accuracy* of system timers and schedulers